# How in Tcl/Tk to center an image horizontally within a canvas element while use bbox all to set the scroll region?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm attempting to display scans of textual content that are shaped much like newspaper articles within a canvas scroll region.  Most of the images are of the same width but, if some vary slightly, I'd like to center the image horizontally in the canvas.

If the line `.canvas configure -scrollregion [.canvas bbox all]` is commented out below, then the image is centered; but when it is not commented out, the image is as if anchored nw 0 0.

Is it possible to center the image and calculate the scrollregion together in this manner  or must the image dimensions be used to calculate the scrollregion?

Thank you.

```
tk::canvas .canvas -width 500 -background white -yscrollcommand ".v set" -xscrollcommand ".h set"
.canvas create image 250 25 -image $img -anchor n
.canvas configure -scrollregion [.canvas bbox all]

grid .canvas -sticky nwes -column 0 -row 0
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 1

grid [ttk::scrollbar .h -orient horizontal -command ".canvas xview"] -column 0 -row 1 -sticky we
grid [ttk::scrollbar .v -orient vertical -command ".canvas yview" ] -column 1 -row 0 -sticky ns
```

Removing the `.canvas configure -scrollregion [.canvas bbox all]` and changing the first two lines to the three below, including the image height centers it horizontally; but `-scrollregion` will need to be recalculated with each image change as one steps through the scans.

```
set h [ expr { [image height $img] + 50 }]
tk::canvas .canvas -width 500 -background white -scrollregion "0 0 500 $h" -yscrollcommand ".v set" -xscrollcommand ".h set"
.canvas create image 250 25 -image $img -anchor n
```